# How to use mongo changestream diff

Tags: .net, mongodb, bson, changestream

Mongo changestreams can send just the diff of changes as bson.

Can the diffs be easily applied to the previous version of the bson document?

There's a method on `BsonDocument` called `Merge` but it doesn't seem to do what I want. Specifically the array changes are labelled for example as `ArrayName.0`, which creates a property with that name instead of updating the 0th element in the array.

Comment: I've provided an answer to this on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ag7PAOPuPQk